# m stations are connected to a single router. The first station transmits p packets per unit time and the i-th station is twice as fast as i-1 station

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

**Question:** $m$ stations are connected to a single router. The first station transmits $p$ packets per unit time and the $i-th$ station is twice as fast as the $(i-1)st$ station. How many packets does the router receive per unit time?

**Approach:**  Total stations = $2^m$ I would assume the router per unit would receive: $p*(2^m -1)$

Does this calculation make sense to approach this problem?

Comment: Total stations $2^m$? Isn't number of stations $m$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may certainly not be the most qualified person to answer this question but yes you're right. The most expressive part of your problem is the phrase ' i-th station is twice as fast as the (i-1)th station'. This one clearly models a geometric progression since the ratio between two consecutive terms in a geometric distribution is constant, in this case equal to 2.

So you can consider the number of terms as *m*, ratio *q*= 2 and first term *p*. Now you can apply the sum formula for the series:

$ S_m = p * \frac{q^m - 1}{q -1 }$

Plugging in the values we come up with the formula:

$ S_m = p * (2 ^m -1)$

$S_m$ where m is finite is the number of packets the router gets per unit of time from m sources.
Also this question has nothing to do with probability and $2^m$ as far as I'm aware doesn't have any physical meaning in this case.

Answer (score 1):

First station sends $p$ packets.

$k$-th station sends $2^{k-1}p$ packets.

Total packets sent:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}2^ip = p\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}2^i = p(2^m-1)$$

So, yes, your calculation is correct, but writing it out will make that more clear.